# How to hide grid lines and x-axis labels in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js v3.2.0 and I want to disable the grid lines and x-axis labels. I've tried various examples from other stack overflow posts but none seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcp95hjf/1/

html

```
<div style = "width: 600px; height: 400px;">
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="1" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

js

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132,1)'
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: false,
            ticks: {
              display: false //this will remove only the label
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display:false
          }]      
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty strange, even on their official websites example parameters are also not getting applied.

Comment: Maybe the documentation is not updated for the new v3 version?

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js v3 has multiple breaking changes, one of them is how you define the scales, it is stated in the migration guide and shown in a lot of the examples (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

You will have to change `scales: { yAxes: [], xAxes: []}` to `scales: { y: {}, x: {}}`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/r26h71fm/2/

Answer (score 1):

Hide GridLines on Both Axis -

ChartJS v2 (older version) -

```
scales: {
    x: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],

    y: [
      {
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Newer Version ChartJS v3 -

```
scales: {
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },

    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
```